# SSIS Merge Join losing column length for string column

Tags: sql-server, ssis

SSIS Merge Join is not preserving the character length of an input string column from the two input tables. How do I fix this?

- I have two `sort transforms` feeding into a merge join transform.
- I have verified that both of the output columns in question on both of the sort transforms are of length **32** and both have the same name, using the advanced editor.
- I perform a `left outer join` in `merge transform` editor and verify by hovering over the column name in the diagram that the input is of length **32**.

However, the **output** column is of length **50** and this causes a validation warning about truncation. I don't see and advanced editor option for the merge join so I don't know why this is happening or how to fix it.

Anybody deal with this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative solution, if you don't want to delete the transformation and then add it back again (what a PITA), is to edit the XML and update the property cachedLength= for the column in the merge join.

I wish Microsoft would fix this.

Answer (score 2):

So, I finally figured out ***a*** solution to this. Remove the `merge join transform` and add it back. It seems that the input column was initially set to 50 and the `merge join transform` evidently caches the largest size of the column. If I increased the size of the column from the data source the column size in the `merge join transform` would also increase, but when I reduced the size of the column it stays at the large size. I could find no way to refresh this metadata without removing the component and re-adding it.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the merge join transform and add it back and re-mapping all the columns works.